# How to update element in ng-repeat list when duplicated key object gets added

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<table>
    //thead[...]
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users track by user.username">
        <td>{{user.username}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

Whenever I add an element (`$scope.users.push(newUser);`) whose key is duplicated in the ng-repeat list, I get the error:

`Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. Repeater: user in users, Duplicate key: username`

I am okay with this, but I want the old object to be updated with the values of the new one. In other words, I want it updated or replaced.

I could not find any help in google, so I'm lost.

Comment: You could try .splice instead of push to add/remove (basically replace) an item in the array.

Comment: I suspect youre gonna have to look through users and find the duplicate key and update the object manually, but i dont understand the problem well enough myself to be certain of that as a solution

Comment: @DeborahK That worked very well! You should make a reply so I can accept it. :)!

Comment: Seems like it worked by chance. I thought that angular had prototyped some custom indexOf function to its scope variables, which I used to get the desired index to splice, but I tried again and seems to behave as normal array's indexOf. I probably will have to do what @onaclov2000 said.

Answer (score 0):

Use .splice instead of .push to add/remove (basically replace) the items in the array.

Comment: I'm afraid I was actually deceived by my set up. This answer by itself is not complete, because it lacks the part in which the desired index is found. I will have to uncheck it for now. I'm sorry. :(

Answer (score 0):

Annoying as it may be something like (more of a pseudocode since I really don't know most of your code):

```
for (var i =0; i <=length_of_array; i++){
   if  (array[i].admin == new_element.admin)
   {
       array[i] = new_element;
      new_element =null;
   }
}
if (new_element != null)
{
   array.push(new_element)
}
```

Like I said without any more context that's basically what I'd recommend, I'm not an expert at angular but unless there is a specific angular solution that I'm not aware of, this is an alternate option in the meantime.

Comment: I was looking forward to find a way through angularJS API, but I guess this is what I will have to do after all. Shouldn't it be `!=` instead of `==` when you check if it was updated in the loop?

Comment: Yes the second one should have been checking that we hadnt done a swap, you could alternately use a control variable, i just figured if youve replaced the value in the array, setting the new element to null shouldnt be a big deal